# Quotient rule differential calculus

Tags: calculus

this is my first encounter with derivatives. I just don't know what to do if there is an square root in quotient rule. $$\frac{t^2+3t+1}{\sqrt{t}+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

write it like $$\sqrt{t}=t^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

then apply $$(x^n)'=nx^{(n-1)}$$

when you take  the derivative

There's also (another table one):

$$(\sqrt{x})'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

but the first way is the easiest one

Answer (score 1):

For the quotient rule:

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' =\frac {fg'-gf'}{g^2}$$

In the answer above given by Dr. Graubner, I would leave $(\sqrt {t} + 1)^2$ as-is unless there's a reason to simplify further.

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\frac{(2t+3)(\sqrt{t}+1)-(t^2+3t+1)\frac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}}{(\sqrt{t}+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is

Possibility 1

$$ t^2+3t+\frac{1}{\sqrt {t+1}}$$

Chain rule states that

$$y=F(g(x))$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g'(x)F'(g(x))$$

So, your question is

$$ y=t^2+3t+\frac{1}{\sqrt {t+1}}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2t+3-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t+1}}$$

Possibility 2

$$y=\frac{t^2+3t+1}{\sqrt {t+1}}$$

Quotient rule of differentiation

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{3t^2+7t+5}{2(t+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$